# How to check that a value has specific type

Tags: typescript

I want typescript to check value to match specific type without actually invoking this
What is the most elegant way to do this rather than I have described below?

Consider the following example:

```js
import { OdbEventProcessorFunc } from "./OdbEventProcessor";

export function tviewEventProcessor() {
    // some implementation here... doesn't matter for the question
}

// The ugly way to do the job:
function unused_just_for_type_check_of_the_function() {
    // The following line checks that function 'tviewEventProcessor' is actually 'OdbEventProcessorFunc' and raise TS2322 error if it's not
    const unused_just_for_type_check_of_the_function2: OdbEventProcessorFunc = tviewEventProcessor; 
}
```

The code above does what I need, and I actually use it rare cases when I need it.
But I wonder if there is a better way to do this?

Some kind of

```js
typescript_please_check_that(tviewEventProcessor is OdbEventProcessorFunc )
```

What struggles me in existing approach is:

- Its ugly and long to write
- It creates some code that can be bundled. Though it should be stripped by treeshaking, but anyway

Additional Q&A:
Q: Why doing it like this and not typecheck on caller side?
A: Because when I change definition of 'OdbEventProcessorFunc' I want IDE to navigate me with TS2322 errors not to the callers of this function, but to its definiton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an arrow function instead (which, as an expression rather than a function declaration, can be easily type-checked without any extra baggage), you can export and check the type at the same time. For example:

```
type Fn = (arg: string) => number;

export const fn: Fn = (arg: string) => {
    return 5;
};
```

If you stay with a `function`, you can use a [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) that isn't used anywhere else to typecheck.

```
type Fn = (arg: string) => number;

export const fn = (arg: string) => {
    return 5;
};
fn satisfies Fn;
```

No need to wrap it in a function, or to have any emitted code there.